# Perrin sequence help c++

Tags: c++

Hey everyone I am trying to write a recursive function for a perrin sequence where it returns the nth term that a user enters which is:

```
P(0) = 3, P(1) = 0, P(2) = 2,
```

and

```
P(n) = P(n − 2) + P(n − 3) for n > 2.
```

The sequence of Perrin numbers starts with

```
3, 0, 2, 3, 2, 5, 5, 7, 10, 12, 17, 22, 29, 39 ...
```

I know I should put some sort of code in here but I am totally lost. We just learned recursive functions this week and I cannot figure out how to do this.

Comment: Since this is a very simple problem (no offense intended), I think the only productive way to help you (as opposed to simply showing you the answer) is to ask several questions about what you do and don't understand until we can pin down exactly what is preventing you from solving this yourself. In other words: Perhaps we should discuss this in chat.

Answer (score 1):

This could be a good way to start with TDD.

- First write method p in that way it returns 3 if argument is equal to 0

  - You assert that via checking if p(0) == 3
  - run the program
- Then you modify method p that it returns 0 if argument is equal to 1

  - You assert that via checking if p(1) == 0
  - run the program (you might guessed it)
- Then you modify method p that it returns 2 if argument is equal to 2

  - You assert that via checking if p(2) == 2
  - run the program (you might guessed it already)

Small hint: all checks/test must be okay - not in a series, but all together.

Yeah you did it the first part for the first three numbers.

- then you modify the method to enter a special branch if n is larger than 2

  - Now comes the interesting part what to return here?
  - write a test which asserts that p(3) == 3
  - try something to make it return the value 3
  - maybe plainly return p(0)
  - run the program (you might guessed it already too)
- write a test which asserts that p(4) == 2

  - you fail, now try something else
  - return the sum of p(n-2) and p(n-3)
  - run the program (did that?)
  - assert more values....
  - run the program (you should know that now.)

Comment: This was the best advice! Thank you for not just giving me the answer. This was a great way to figure it out. I was over thinking it by thinking that I needed an equation or something to have this work but making it recursive made it so easy. Thanks!